# Generate all combinations of certain digits

Tags: python, python-2.x, combinatorics, generator

Related to [another answer of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/110955/78136) on Project Euler 35, I found the need to calculate all combinations of certain digits, i.e. 1, 3, 7 and 9, below a given `n`. I looked around, and didn't find any really good premade solutions, but found some bits and pieces related to Cartesian products, and collated my findings into the following code:

```
import itertools

def all_digit_combinations(allowed_digits, maximum):
    """Yield all combinations of allowed_digits below maximum.

    For allowed_digits being a list of single digits, i.e. [1, 3, 7, 9],
    combine all variants of these digits until we pass the maximum value.
    """
    no_of_digits = 1

    while True:
        for digit_tuple in itertools.product(allowed_digits, repeat=no_of_digits):
            new_number = reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, digit_tuple)
            if new_number < maximum:
                yield new_number
            else:
                raise StopIteration

        no_of_digits += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ', '.join(map(str, all_digit_combinations([1, 3, 7, 9], 100)))
    print ', '.join(map(str, all_digit_combinations([3, 5], 1000)))
```

Which indeed prints the expected output of:

```
1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19, 31, 33, 37, 39, 71, 73, 77, 79, 91, 93, 97, 99
3, 5, 33, 35, 53, 55, 333, 335, 353, 355, 533, 535, 553, 555
```

I first tried using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()` and other variations from itertools, but some of those versions failed to include numbers like 31 and 73. But it I could very well simply not use the correct parameters.

Can you review this code, suggesting any optimalisations or improvements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the code that you have is near best it can become.

I would however use a more functional/iterator based solution.

1. `while True: no_of_digits += 1` can be replaced with a for loop.
   This is by using `itertools.count(1)`. (Careful infinite generator here)
2. `all_digit_combinations` would imply to me, that I get all of them, even 55555555.
   Instead I would make `all_digit_combinations` an infinite generator.
3. `else: raise StopIteration` is kinda ugly. Personally I would use `itertool.takewhile`. (In this case it's better than filter, as infinite's are involved.)

   As an alternate to itertools, you could just `return`. But due to that being implicit, it may be disliked.

And so I would re-write it into this:

```
def all_digit_combinations(allowed_digits):
    return (
        reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, digit_tuple)
        for no_of_digits in itertools.count(1)
        for digit_tuple in itertools.product(allowed_digits, repeat=no_of_digits)
    )

def digit_combinations(allowed_digits, maximum):
    return itertools.takewhile(
        lambda x: x < maximum,
        all_digit_combinations(allowed_digits)
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ', '.join(map(str, digit_combinations([1, 3, 7, 9], 100)))
    print ', '.join(map(str, digit_combinations([3, 5], 1000)))
```

---

As a performance is concern, your code is quite a bit faster than mine.
I used the following code:

```
import itertools
import timeit
from functools import wraps

def all_digit_combinations_original(allowed_digits, maximum):
    no_of_digits = 1
    while True:
        for digit_tuple in itertools.product(allowed_digits, repeat=no_of_digits):
            new_number = reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, digit_tuple)
            if new_number < maximum:
                yield new_number
            else:
                raise StopIteration
        no_of_digits += 1

def all_digit_combinations_enhanced(allowed_digits, maximum):
    for no_of_digits in itertools.count(1):
        for digit_tuple in itertools.product(allowed_digits, repeat=no_of_digits):
            new_number = reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, digit_tuple)
            if new_number < maximum:
                yield new_number
            else:
                raise StopIteration

def all_digit_combinations_answer(allowed_digits):
    return (
        reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, digit_tuple)
        for no_of_digits in itertools.count(1)
        for digit_tuple in itertools.product(allowed_digits, repeat=no_of_digits)
    )

def digit_combinations_answer(allowed_digits, maximum):
    return itertools.takewhile(
        lambda x: x < maximum,
        all_digit_combinations_answer(allowed_digits)
    )

def digit_combinations_enhanced(allowed_digits, maximum):
    return itertools.takewhile(
        lambda x: x < maximum,
        (
            reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, digit_tuple)
            for no_of_digits in itertools.count(1)
            for digit_tuple in itertools.product(allowed_digits, repeat=no_of_digits)
        )
    )

def timer_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def run():
            list(fn(*args, **kwargs))
        return run
    return wrapper

def timeit_(fn):
    print fn.__name__, timeit.timeit(fn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    timer = timer_wrapper([1, 3, 7, 9], 100)
    timeit_(timer(all_digit_combinations_original))
    timeit_(timer(digit_combinations_answer))
    timeit_(timer(all_digit_combinations_enhanced))
    timeit_(timer(digit_combinations_enhanced))

    timer = timer_wrapper([3, 5], 1000)
    timeit_(timer(all_digit_combinations_original))
    timeit_(timer(digit_combinations_answer))
    timeit_(timer(all_digit_combinations_enhanced))
    timeit_(timer(digit_combinations_enhanced))
```

I obtained the following benchmarks.

```
all_digit_combinations_original 14.666793108
digit_combinations_answer 18.1881940365
all_digit_combinations_enhanced 15.228415966
digit_combinations_enhanced 17.9368011951

all_digit_combinations_original 14.4108960629
digit_combinations_answer 17.2161641121
all_digit_combinations_enhanced 14.8418960571
digit_combinations_enhanced 17.1169350147
```

Comment: Interesting benchmarks. With this information, it's probably possible to find a third implementation which is faster than both AND idiomatic.

Answer (score 5):

You can improve performance by changing the `reduce` into a simple `sum` if you take the `product` from lists of ones, tens, hundreds etc.

```
import itertools

def digit_combinations_jk(allowed_digits, maximum):
    choices = [allowed_digits]
    while True:
        for terms in itertools.product(*choices):
            new_number = sum(terms)
            if new_number < maximum:
                yield new_number
            else:
                return
        choices.insert(0, [10 * x for x in choices[0]])
```

Joe Wallis's benchmark:

```
all_digit_combinations_original 12.2259960175
digit_combinations_answer 15.1491339207
all_digit_combinations_enhanced 12.3741300106
digit_combinations_enhanced 14.9268059731
digit_combinations_jk 8.92141604424

all_digit_combinations_original 11.867401123
digit_combinations_answer 14.2185270786
all_digit_combinations_enhanced 11.9946269989
digit_combinations_enhanced 14.0026550293
digit_combinations_jk 8.62084293365
```